# Pull to refresh not working when I load the project in expo

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I have a simple app displaying a FlatList on the screen.

When I refresh the screen it triggers methods that will fetch new data from an API.

On the web interface it works well, I press F5 and the new data are fetched.

When I switch to android it doesn't work. I do the movement to refresh the screen but nothing happens.

To obtain the app on android I scan QR code generated by the Metro server with the expo app.

It's like it was stuck or something.

Here is my code so far :

HomeScreen.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

export default function HomeScreen( { route, navigation, data, refreshing, onRefresh } ) {
        console.log(data);
        return(
                <View style={style.container}>
                        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
                        <Text style={style.titleContainer}>CityWeather</Text>
                        <FlatList
                                data={data}
                                refreshing={refreshing}
                                onRefresh={onRefresh}
                                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                                renderItem={({item, index}) => (
                                        <View>
                                                <Text>{item.temp} C - {item.name}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                        )
                                }
                        />
                </View>
        );
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
        container:
                {
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        flex: 1,
                        backgroundColor: '#fff',
                },
        titleContainer:
                        {
                                width: '100%',
                                paddingBottom: 15,
                                paddingTop: 40,
                                backgroundColor: 'black',
                                color: 'white',
                                textAlign: 'center'
                        }
});
```

App.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import HomeScreen from './app/screens/HomeScreen.js'


export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);                                           
        var navigation = this.props.navigation;             
        this.state = {                                      
            cities: [
                    {
                        name: 'London',
                        country: 'UK'
                    },
                    {       
                        name: 'Edinburgh',
                        country: 'UK'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'New York',
                        country: 'US'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Texas',
                        country: 'US'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Washington',
                        country: 'US'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Paris',
                        country: 'France'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Doha',
                        country: 'Qatar'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Sydney',
                        country: 'Australia'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Cancun',
                        country: 'Mexico'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Madrid',
                        country: 'Spain'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Berlin',
                        country: 'Germany'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Brussels',
                        country: 'Belgium'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Copenhagen',
                        country: 'Denmark'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Athens',
                        country: 'Greece'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'New Delhi',
                        country: 'India'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Dublin',
                        country: 'Ireland'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Rome',
                        country: 'Italy'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Tokyo',
                        country: 'Japan'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Wellington',
                        country: 'New Zealand'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Amsterdam',
                        country: 'Netherlands'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Ohio',
                        country: 'Norway'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Panama City',
                        country: 'Panama'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Lisbon',
                        country: 'Portugal'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Warsaw',
                        country: 'Poland'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Moscow',
                        country: 'Russia'
                    }
            ],
            list: [],
            refresh: true

        };

        this.apikey = 'key';
        this.fetchTemperatures();
    }

    fetchTemperatures = () => {
        var currentCities = []
        this.getRandomCities(this.state.cities, 12).forEach(city => this.fetchCityTemp(city.name, city.country, currentCities));
    }

    getRandomCities = (cities, numberOfCities) => {
        var shuffle = require('shuffle-array');
        var randomizedCities = shuffle(cities).slice(0, numberOfCities);
        return randomizedCities;
    }

    fetchCityTemp = ( city, country, currentCities ) => {
        var apiURL =  'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city+','+country+'&appid='+this.apikey+'&units=metric';
        fetch(apiURL).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            var r = responseJson.main;
            var currentResponse = responseJson;
            var city = {
                name: currentResponse.name,
                country: country,
                temp: Math.ceil(r.temp),
                type: currentResponse.weather[0].main
            };
            currentCities.push(city);
            console.log("BEFORE UPDATE ", this.state.list);
            this.setState({
                list: currentCities,
                refresh: true,
            })
            console.log("AFTER UPDATE ", this.state.list);
        });

    }


    loadNewTemps = () => {
        this.setState({
            list: [],
            refresh: true,
        });
        this.fetchTemperatures();
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator>
                                    <Stack.Screen name="Home" options={{headerShown: false}}>
                                        {props => <HomeScreen {...props} data={this.state.list} refreshing={this.state.refresh} onRefresh={this.state.loadNewTemps}/> }
                                    </Stack.Screen>
                                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
    }
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong and it seems to work fine on the web interface.

Comment: was it supposed to be this.loadNewTemps?

Comment: It's a method that I call to reload the list of cities that I display.

Comment: yeah but it's not a state, it's a function. Instead of this.state.loadNewTemps, you could try this.loadNewTemps

Comment: Yes you were right it was just a dumb code error from me. The method isn't in state my initial post is irrelevant thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **refreshControl** attr to your FlatList and fetch data in the **onRefresh** callback method as below:

```
              <FlatList
                refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl
                        colors={[AppTheme.colors.primary]}
                        tintColor={AppTheme.colors.primary}
                        refreshing={refreshing}
                        onRefresh={() => {
                            //fetch data here
                            console.log("refreshing");
                              
                        }}
                    />
                }
              //other attributes go here...
              />
```

Comment: I just made a code error on the reference I pass to the component. What should bring the refreshControl ? (I'm a noob)

Comment: @RobertReynolds you can import it from the RN framework: import { View, FlatList, RefreshControl } from "react-native";